# Keeping input/output separated in Java console application

Tags: java, console, console-application

I am writing a console application in Java. It is similar to a chat client: Input and output are asynchronously made. The problem is that if some output is made while the user is in the middle of typing, the lines will get mixed up on the screen.

I am looking for a solution which allows me to have a input area separate from the output area. At the moment I am using an extra thread which polls a BufferedReader on System.in.

The program needs to run on a Linux server and be accessed via an ssh session. So any hints that only work in this environment are fine.

Are there any high level libraries which can do this? Or is there a smart trick using terminal / ANSI codes? The ANSI codes s (save cursor) and r (restore cursor) might be helpful but how do i know where to jump to do the output and how do i handle scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall a long time ago working with similar things but in C++. I was using the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library then. Check out [javacurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) which seems to be a Java implementation of something like ncurses.

Comment: although i like the library due to nostalgia. it has its flare. but it's a complete widget library. you could take any widget library (e.g. AWT, SWT) and make two text areas for this purpose. if there is not any short snippet on how to separate in and out, i don't see the point in using jcurses

Comment: @kewlbfy OP needed a solution that works in a terminal. The widget libraries you mention do not work in that context afaik

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use Curses. [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) is a Java implementation of the Curses library and will give you control of the terminal to allow scrolling, positioning etc.